# Лабиринт в консоли. Проверка на стену.

Tags: c++

Не знаю как сделать проверку символа

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    const int K_LEFT = 75;
    const int K_RIGHT = 77;
    const int K_DOWN = 80;
    const int K_UP = 72;
    const int K_ESC = 27;
    bool flag = true;
    int c;
    int x,y;
    cout << "11111H111" << endl;
    cout << "100010100" << endl;
    cout << "101000101" << endl;
    cout << "101010101" << endl;
    cout << "100000101" << endl;
    cout << "101111101" << endl;
    cout << "100100001" << endl;
    cout << "110001111" << endl;
    cout << "111111111" << endl;
    x = 5;
    y = 0;
    system("color 6");
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD position = {x, y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
    while ((flag) && (c = getch()))
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case K_UP: y--; //Вверх       // Тут нужно делать проверку
            break;                    // Напримерэ
        case K_LEFT: x--; //Влево     // Если верхний символ равен 1 то
            break;                    // ничего не делать
        case K_RIGHT: x++; //Вправо   //
            break;                    //
        case K_DOWN: y++; //Вниз      //
            break;                    //
        case K_ESC:
            flag = false;
            break;
        default: 
            break;
        }
        position.Y=0;
        position.X=0;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
        cout << "111111111" <<endl;
        cout << "100010100" <<endl;
        cout << "101000101" <<endl;
        cout << "101010101" <<endl;
        cout << "100000101" <<endl;
        cout << "101111101" <<endl;
        cout << "100100001" <<endl;
        cout << "110001111" <<endl;
        cout << "111111111" <<endl;
        position.Y=y;
        position.X=x;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
        cout << "H";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Храните лабиринт в массиве. Например -1 - персонаж, 0 - пустое место, 1  - стена. Тогда если игрок в array[3][3] и нажато "Вниз" вы провяряете ячейку массива ниже, и осуществляете действие.